# 'Home' is defined but never used no-unused-vars".*

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React.

I've made a component called Avatar which I want to link to a home page if clicked.

**When compiling I get the following error: "Line 9:12:  'Home' is defined but never used no-unused-vars".*

**So, my question is how do I correctly link the Avatar Icon to Home that's declared in ./Auth.js ?**

**BookList.js**
Here is my current code.

```js
import React from "react";
import Book from "./Book";
import { BookContext } from "../context/BookContext";
import { ThemeContext } from "../context/ThemeContext";
import "./index.css";
import "./BookList.css";
import Avatar from "./Avatar"
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Auth";


const RouteAvatarClick = () => {
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Route exact path="/Home"> //Tried to link Home from ./Auth 
      <Avatar />
    </Route>
  </BrowserRouter>
}
export default class BookList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Consumer>
        {(contextTheme) => (
          <BookContext.Consumer>
            {(contextBook) => {
              const { books } = contextBook;

              const { changeColorTheme, isDarkMode, dark, light} = contextTheme;

              const theme = isDarkMode ? dark : light; //Conditional

              return (
                <section className="page-section" style={{ backgroundColor: theme.bg, color: theme.color }} id="portfolio">
                  <div className="container">
                    <div><RouteAvatarClick/></div>
                    <div className="text-right"><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={changeColorTheme}>Change Mood</button></div>
                    <div className="text-center">
                      <h2 className="section-heading text-uppercase">My Book Folio</h2>
                      <h3 className="section-subheading text-muted">Books I would like to read.</h3></div>
                    <div className="row">
                      {books.map((book, index) => {
                        return <Book book={book} key={index} />;
                      })}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
              );
            }}
          </BookContext.Consumer>
        )}
      </ThemeContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

**Avatar.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import "./Avatar.css";

const Avatar = ({className, src, alt, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <div>
    {src? (
      <img className={`defaultClass ${className}`}
        src={src}
        alt={alt}
      />
    ) : (
      <img
        {...props} //If we want to use other images
        className={`defaultClass ${className}`}
        src={"https://i.pinimg.com/736x/49/f7/25/49f725a9f2b62ea80603f3fe51289735--le-design-icon-design.jpg"}
        alt={alt}
      />
    )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Avatar
```

**Auth.js**

```js
import React from "react";

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h1 className="title is-1">This is the Home Page</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras gravida,
      risus at dapibus aliquet, elit quam scelerisque tortor, nec accumsan eros
      nulla interdum justo. Pellentesque dignissim, sapien et congue rutrum,
      lorem tortor dapibus turpis, sit amet vestibulum eros mi et odio.
    </p>
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```

**Please don't hesitate to let me know if there's a way to improve my question**

Comment: You are referring to it in the template tags but it is quoted and has a "/" before it.

Comment: try using the mustache syntax instead {{ Home }}  instead of the quotes.  I am not sure though, thats just how it works in vue

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Currently in your `RouteAvatarClick` component, you've provided the path ("/Home"), but not the element/component to render when the user is on that route. Try something like this in your `RouteAvatarClick` component:

`<Route exact path="/Home" element={<Home />}>`

Then navigate to `/Home` in your browser (`http:localhost:3000/Home`) and see if that helps! <3

P.S. The `element` prop is assuming you're using react-router v6. If you're using v5, it'll be `component={Home}`.

Comment: It's helped to remove the error. The page is rendering bank, however at least I'm one step closer! Thank you!

Comment: Strange @Fury ... have you returned the component content from all the places? (that often gets me )